# Combining 2 tables without losing any data

Tags: sql, sql-server

My first table (actually a view) is:

```
SELECT * FROM VW_MAIN_INFO
```

My second table is:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES
```

In a query, I combine both like this:

```
SELECT TP.TYPE,VMI.*
FROM VW_MAIN_INFO VMI,
     TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES TP
WHERE VMI.START_INLET_TEMP=TP.TEMP1
AND   VMI.START_OUTLET_TEMP=TP.TEMP2
AND   VMI.TIME_FORMATTED=CONVERT(DATETIME, TP.DATE, 101)
```

What you can tell, what really matters for me in the second table (TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES) is the field "TYPE".

What do I need help with:

I need to return everything from VW_MAIN_INFO and TYPE (from TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES).

- However, if I cannot find a type in TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES, I should return a specific value (for example, "EMPTY" or null).

How can I achieve? Is the best path to use "minus" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059296/compare-two-tables-with-minus-operation-in-oracle)?

Finally, my problem with minus is that I don't have the same structure in both tables.

Any help? Ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?

Comment: You need to use a LEFT JOIN and ISNULL.

Comment: read up on tyes of JOIN - LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER

Comment: @Fabio Soares - can you give column which is common in both tables

Comment: I notice that your query really reads like PLSQL, and you reference MINUS which is an oracle concept (the companion SQL Server command is 'EXCEPT')  Do you need to update tags and remove sql-server and add Oracle?  You'll probably get better help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  TP.TYPE ,
        VMI.*
FROM    VW_MAIN_INFO VMI
        LEFT JOIN TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES TP ON VMI.START_INLET_TEMP = TP.TEMP1
                                              AND VMI.START_OUTLET_TEMP = TP.TEMP2
                                              AND VMI.TIME_FORMATTED = CONVERT(DATETIME, TP.DATE, 101);
```